# Fast Simulations with Compile

Tags: performance-tuning, random, simulation, stochastic-calculus

this post relates to another post that I didn't follow up propely. If I wanted to simulate
a system of stochastic proesses like the following, and loop over this run many many times 
would writing the processes as 'compiled' pure functions speed up the run time? Or, is Nestlist already trying to do this for me?

```
norTheta[mu_, sigma_] := Random[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma]];
norPi[mu_, sigma_] := Random[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma]];

thetaNext[thetaNow_] := 
thetaNow + (-lambdaTheta*(thetaNow - thetaBar)*deltaT 
+ sigmaTheta*norTheta[0, 1]*Sqrt[deltaT]);
piNext[piNow_, thetaNow_] := piNow + (-lambdaPi*(piNow - thetaNow)*deltaT + 
sigmaPi*norPi[0, 1]*Sqrt[deltaT]);

lambdaTheta = 0.07; sigmaTheta = 1.2; thetaBar = 2; lambdaPi = 1.0; 
sigmaPi = 1.25; deltaT = 1/12;
steps = 252;
T = 5; 
deltaT = 1/steps; // N 
Maturity = T*steps;

simulateRun = Transpose[NestList[{piNext[#[[1]], #[[2]]],
                        thetaNext[#[[2]]]} &, {2, 2}, Maturity]];
```

Comment: Check `simulateRun[[1, 3]]` after evaluating the above code. There is something wrong in your function call `thetaNext[#[[1]], #[[2]]]`. You have defined it as a single argument function before hand.

Comment: sorry, yes, I hadn't actually run the code. I've fixed and edited this above.

Comment: If it is possible to generate all your random data in advance and then access it with an incrementing index (`list[[i++]]`) that should be somewhat faster, for what it's worth.

Comment: ok - thanks, that is possible.

Comment: I added an answer that as well as another optimization.  Please let me know if these are applicable to your real problem, or if you have trouble understanding or implementing them.

Comment: How close is this example to your actual problem?  Looking a second time I think this specific example can be further optimized, but I'd like to confirm that it will be useful before I proceed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are trying to implement [Euler-Maruyama simulation method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method) for a 2-stage short-term [interest rate model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-rate_model#Multi-factor_short-rate_models) which is given by the following system of SDEs:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
     \mathrm{d} \theta_t &=& -\lambda_\theta \left( \theta_t - \bar\theta\right) \mathrm{d}t + \sigma_\theta \mathrm{d}W_{\theta,t} \\
   \mathrm{d} \pi_t &=& -\lambda_\pi\left( \theta_t - \pi_t \right) \mathrm{d}t + \sigma_\pi \mathrm{d} W_{\pi,t}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where $W_\theta$ and $W_\pi$ are independent standard Wiener processes.

Here is the compiled code implementing the above.

```
cfEM = Compile[{{lambdaTheta, _Real}, {thetaBar, _Real}, {sigmaTheta, \
_Real}, {lambdaPi, _Real}, {sigmaPi, _Real}, {th0, _Real}, {pi0, \
_Real}, {dt, _Real}, {steps, _Integer}}, 
   Module[{zs, bag, thc, pic, zths, zpis},
    zths = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[dt]], steps];
    zpis = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[dt]], steps];
    thc = th0; pic = pi0;
    bag = Internal`Bag[{thc, pic}];
    Do[
     pic += -lambdaPi dt (pic - thc) + sigmaPi zpis[[k]];
     thc += -lambdaTheta dt (thc - thetaBar) + sigmaTheta zths[[k]];
     Internal`StuffBag[bag, {thc, pic}, 1];
     , {k, 1, steps}];
    Partition[Internal`BagPart[bag, All], 2]
    ]
   ];
```

Call example:

```
In[14]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 Length[data = cfEM[0.07, 2., 1.2, 1, 1.25, 2., 2., 1/252., 5 252]]]

Out[14]= {0., 1261}
```

[image]

Note, however, that Euler-Maruyama method is only approximate, while your system of SDEs is Gaussian. An exact simulation method, known as Ozaki method, is available and is not hard to code. See this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387758380) for the details of the 1D case. You would need to generalize it to the 2D case, but it is not very hard.

Comment: ...Or I could just wait for Sasha to come along and make my answer look silly. :^)

Comment: Wow, great answer. Well, actually its an inflation process with a stochastic target, 
but yes it is also a commonly deployed short rate model. I 'm trying to migrate to MMA --- this gives me good encouragement. My actual system is a bit more funky than this example but I shall check out the Ozaki method - thank a lot

Comment: So for those who couldn't buy the book, what does the Ozaki method achieve? Thanks :)

Comment: It's exact on SDEs with linear drift and constant diffusion, where Euler-Maruyama or Milstein are only approximate in the strong sense.

Answer (score 8):

There are two areas for optimization that I see here.

The first, if possible, is to generate all your random data in advance and then access it with an incrementing index, e.g. `list[[i++]]`.

The second is to partially evaluate the definitions of `thetaNext` and `piNext` for a given set of parameters.

**A note**: `Random` has been deprecated for some time now and may produce inferior results.  You should be using `RandomReal`/`RandomInteger` in version 7 or `RandomVariate` in version 8.

#### Update

Here is a cleaner implementation of my recommendations.  Should this be inapplicable my original code is visible in the edit history of this post.

Given your definitions and parameters:

```
thetaNext[thetaNow_] := 
  thetaNow + (-lambdaTheta*(thetaNow - thetaBar)*deltaT + 
     sigmaTheta*norTheta[0, 1]*Sqrt[deltaT]);

piNext[piNow_, thetaNow_] := 
  piNow + (-lambdaPi*(piNow - thetaNow)*deltaT + 
     sigmaPi*norPi[0, 1]*Sqrt[deltaT]);

lambdaTheta = 0.07; sigmaTheta = 1.2; thetaBar = 2; lambdaPi = 1.0;
sigmaPi = 1.25; deltaT = 1/12;
steps = 15000;
T = 5;
deltaT = 1/steps; // N
Maturity = T*steps;
```

We can reduce the core of your `NestList` function (for these specific parameters) as follows:

```
func =
 Block[{norTheta, norPi, Part},
  Function @@ FullSimplify @ {
     {piNext[#[[1]], #[[2]]], thetaNext[#[[2]]]} /.
      {norPi[0, 1] -> #2[[1]], norTheta[0, 1] -> #2[[2]]}
    }
 ]
```

> ```
> {0.916667 #1[[1]] + 0.0833333 #1[[2]] + 0.360844 #2[[1]], 0.0116667 + 0.994167 #1[[2]] + 0.34641 #2[[2]]} &
> ```

We will use the second argument of this function to insert the random data, which we create with:

```
piList = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], Maturity];
thetaList = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], Maturity];
rands = {piList, thetaList}\[Transpose];
```

(A shorter form exists for this specific data but I am trying to retain some generality.)

And which we use `FoldList` to provide:

```
FoldList[func, {2, 2}, rands]\[Transpose] // Timing // First
```

> 0.219

By comparison your code takes 4.368 seconds on my machine with the same parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both answers provide excellent solutions. Thanks Mr Wizard

Comment: @LuapNalehw (Paul Whelan?) I simplified my method somewhat.

Comment: friends call me Luap

Comment: @Luap -- I'm Paul too, which is why I recognized that. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you can define rands in one step using RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {Maturity, 2}]

Comment: @Faysal yes, that's exactly what I meant by: "A shorter form exists for this specific data but I am trying to retain some generality."