# Simulations with MonteCarlo and Autoregressive methods

Tags: probability-or-statistics, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to find the best-fit trend for my data. Here I just generated it but let's say I don't know my data trend at all.

```
test = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[100, 10], 100];
data = TemporalData[test];
proc = EstimatedProcess[data, ARMAProcess[3, 3]];
forecast = TimeSeriesForecast[proc, data, {5}, Method -> Automatic]
sims = RandomFunction[proc, {0, 10^2}, 4];
ListLinePlot[Join[data["Paths"], sims["Paths"]], 
PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, ColorData[1, 1]], ColorData[10, 1], 
ColorData[10, 2], ColorData[10, 3], ColorData[12, 4]}, 
PlotLegends -> {"data", "Simulations"}, ImageSize -> 550]
```

As results of the fit shows, neither of AutoRegressive methods of *Mathematica* are being fitted to my data. How can I use the Euler-Maruyama method mentioned [here](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/time-series-and-stochastic-differential-equations/strong-convergence-of-euler-maruyama-approximation.html) and disscuded [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14561/fast-simulations-with-compile/14578#14578) for fitting my data and have the fitness test data for it? How can I also do the Monte Carlo simulations for them and show upper, lower bound and mean of simulations on my data?

Comment: Isn't the problem that your data is non-zero mean? A common method is to subtract out the mean, do the fit with zero-mean data, and then add it back at the end. It's just a constant.

Comment: @bills yes you are right.I just notice the mistake in the first line of the code.But still I have fitness problem cause the result table is not giving proper P values .How can I use the Euler-Maruyama?

Comment: Is it imperative to use auto-regressive and/or Monte-Carlo methods? If not, Quantile Regression can be applied [to find the trend](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/quantile-regression-with-b-splines/) and [conditional PDF's](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/estimation-of-conditional-density-distributions/). After finding a sufficient number of PDF's we can form a goodness of fit test.